# Improving SSLSocketFactory setup / first HTTPS request performance

Tags: java, performance, sslsocketfactory

Is it possible to improve the performance of SSLSocketFactory/SSLContext initial setup for making HTTPS requests?

On several machines I tested, **first** HTTPS request takes >600ms, which is unreasonably high for our use case.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
//    System.out.println("creating factory...");
//    SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
//    System.out.println("factory created " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
URL url = new URL("https://example.com");
System.out.println("url created " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
System.out.println("connection opened " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
assert connection.getResponseCode() == 200;
System.out.println("response code retrieved " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

Timing:

```
url created 0
connection opened 656
response code retrieved 0
```

As I found out, most of the time is not actually spent in the connection itself (handshaking, data transfer, ...), but rather in construction of the `SSLSocketFactory`, which happens even before the SSL handshaking starts.

After uncommenting the factory code:

```
creating factory...
factory created 683
url created 1
connection opened 3
response code retrieved 0
```

I've also tried directly creating SSLContext (`SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2"); sc.init(...); ...`), but the performance was almost the same.

**Q**: Is there a particular reason why the context setup is so expensive? Is it possible to speed it up and/or use some alternative library that doesn't suffer from the same initial cost?

Comment: Most of the time is spent constructing and seeding a `SecureRandom`. It happens exactly once. You can move that to earlier in your program execution, but you can't avoid it.

Comment: @user207421 creating `SecureRandom` takes 10-20ms, not 500+

Comment: Constructing *and seeding* it takes 10-20ms? Remarkable.